# office 365 cannot empty deleted items

Tags: microsoft-office-365, outlook-anywhere

I am unable to delete messages from deleted items on O365. Once I select delete all, they appear gone, but only to come back seconds later.

Does anyone have experience with this, as microsoft recommended to delete and recreate the mailbox (which was done 6 months ago and now issue is back?!).

Thanks in advance.